# How Hooks concept works internally in liferay?

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I wanted to know How the application server will take custom jsp If we deploy the hook and If we undeploy the hook again it will take the liferay existing jsp file. How application server will handles this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original JSP file will be renamed from (e.g.) `view.jsp` to `view.portal.jsp` and the hook's version will be copied as the new `view.jsp`. On undeployment this will be reversed. See the [deployment code here](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/deploy/hot/HookHotDeployListener.java#L1240).

As this is a single step process, it will break when two hooks override the same JSP, effectively loosing the original implementation. See [this article](https://www.liferay.com/web/olaf.kock/blog/-/blogs/overriding-jsps-from-multiple-hooks-promising-the-cure) for a solution to the problem